# +=/*=/etc operators on AnyVal types (Int,Double,etc...) in Scala

Tags: scala

Where exactly are the *=/+=/etc methods declared for the subclasses of AnyVal? I assume something special is done for these types because as a val those are invalid but as a var they are fine. Is this just yet more syntatic sugar ? I assume it is turning

```
a *= 5
```

into

```
a = a * 5
```

which obviously fails for a val.  Is this intuition correct? I also assume it only attempts this for AnyVals?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. For *any* class, not only the subclasses of `AnyVal`, if an assignment method does not exists, then `a OP= b` is turned into `a = a OP b`. Mind you, `OP`, in this case, must be non-alphanumeric characters.

This is described on the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (the Scala specification), section 6.12.4.

Comment: And *a* must be mutable, i.e., a **var**.

Comment: So in a related situation,  then for a var `a` which has defined both the say, `OP=` and `OP` methods, does `a OP= b` become `a = a OP b` or `a.OP=(b)` ?

Comment: And to answer my own question, it appears that `OP=` takes precedence (which makes sense) and `OP` is only called if `OP=` doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

A short game of Foo:

```
class Foo (val v: String, val n: String) {
  override def toString : String = v + " : " + n
  def #: (i: Int) : Foo = {
    new Foo (v.substring (i), n.substring (i)) }}

var foo = new Foo ("Martin", "Odersky") 

scala> foo #:= 2
scala> foo
res30: Foo = rtin : ersky

scala> foo #:= 2
scala> foo      
res32: Foo = in : sky

scala> foo #:= 2
scala> foo      
res34: Foo =  : y
```